# How to convert react js array [] to NSArray in iOS and string[] in Android?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I'm working as a newbie on a cross-platform project using react-native and would like to know how should I convert javascript array of string to Java array (String[]) & iOS NSArray.

For ex, 
My JS component is having

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      devices: [],
      selectedDevices:[]
    };
  }
```

My Android Native Module expects as follows -

```
public void disableDevices(String[] deviceNames){
...

}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Why u should convert its array [] to NSArray in iOS and string[] in Android?

Comment: I need to pass this result to native modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of calling a native method with a passing an array. Hope this will help you.

Android

```
@ReactMethod
public void yourMethod(ReadableArray yourArray, final Promise promise) {

}
```

iOS

```
// YourModule.h
+(void) yourMethod:(NSArray *)yourArray resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject;

// YourModule.m
+ (void) yourMethod:(NSArray *)yourArray
                         resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                         rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject
{

}
```

JS

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { YourModule } = NativeModules;
...

YourModule.yourMethod([1, 2, 3]);
```

You can read more about nativeModules [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android#argument-types)